# Typo3 BackendPreview getting cObj throws: Call to a member function enableFields() on null

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In my BackendPreview for a custom content element in typo3 8.7 i'm trying to get a content object with following code in my own service class:

```
            $conf = array(
            'tables' => 'tt_content',
            'source' => $uid,
            'dontCheckPid' => 1
        );

        $this->objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
        $result = $this->objectManager->get(RecordsContentObject::class)->render($conf);
```

Doing this in frontendContext will return the cObj as expected but in BE Context, typo3 throws the exception: "Call to a member function enableFields() on null".

I've tried to initialize the configurationManager manually but no effects.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem, that the ContentObjectRenderer, (responsible for your TypoScript rendering) expects the TSFE  (TypoScriptFrontendController), and since you are not in a FE context but a BE context it won't be initialized.

In theory, you can fake it, but of course it costs performance and I would not recommend it.

If you would like to have a preview, then use this approach:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/AddingYourOwnContentElements/Index.html